# Input files for configure file

Tags: linux, gnu

When building various libraries in linux, I often find myself specifying a lot of library / directory location parameters (e.g. --includedir). Is there a way to aggregate all of these flags into a file and run configure with the commands specified in that file?

For example:

```
./configure < myFile
```

where myFile is:

> --includedir=/local/home/myFolder
>
> --CPPFLAGS="-I/home/foo/include"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a script called configure.sh and add it to your $PATH so you can execute the commands you are looking for. For example:

`#/bin/bash`

`./configure --includedir=/local/home/myFolder -CPPFLAGS="I/home/foo/include"`

To run the script:

```
./configure.sh
```

Comment: What would bob.txt be in this case? As in what would it be used for?

Comment: That can be any argument you would want to pass manually with your command if you need or you can just take it out.

Comment: No problem, anytime!